# Why do rotated math labels look jagged on Adobe Acrobat Reader DC?

Tags: viewers

```
\documentclass[border=15pt,pstricks,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-node,amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid,linejoin=1]
\pnodes(2,3){A}(6,6){C}(6,3){B}(10,6){D}

\pcline(A)(C) \bput{:0}(.4){\text{$\dfrac{\sqrt{20}}{4}$}}
\pcline(A)(C) \naput[nrot=:U]{$\dfrac{\sqrt{12}}{4}+\sqrt[3]{ab}$}
\pcline(A)(C) \lput*{80}(.8){$\dfrac{\sqrt{20}}{4}$}

\pcline(B)(D) \bput(.4){$\dfrac{\sqrt{20}}{4}$}
\pcline(B)(D) \naput{$\dfrac{\sqrt{12}}{4}+\sqrt[3]{ab}$}
\pcline(B)(D) \lput*{90}(.8){$\dfrac{\sqrt{20}}{4}$}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Question: The math labels look jagged on Adobe Acrobat Reader DC. How can I fix it?

[image]

Comment: I get [far better resolution in the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pmxtZ.png) and therefore less jaggedness. Perhaps see if you get bad results in the printing, or when using a different viewer (I used SumatraPDF). You can also attempt to use `\rotatebox` from [`graphicx`](//ctan.org/pkg/graphicx).

Comment: @Werner Oh, thanks for your comment but I am using Acrobat Reader DC.

Comment: `\rotatebox`  does the same. However, you should use a correct question! You do not want to know how `nrot`  works, you want to know why you get such ugly root lines! And this has _nothing_ to do with `nrot`!

Comment: Example compiled with TeXLive on linux, displayed using Adobe Acrobat DC in a Win10 VM, no issues. I had issues with Evince, but they went away when zoomin in. What kind of display settings do you have in your DC?

Comment: @daleif I do not have the knowledge about it. I think my DC get by default.

Comment: You can check it under Edit -> preferences -> Page display

Comment: @daleif See edited question. How can I do?

Comment: Settings look ok, in particular since "smooth line art" is enabled.

Comment: @chishimutoji I also have the same problem with Acrobat Reader. Don't worry, if I use the built-in viewer of VS Code or use Google Chrome to view PDF, there are no problems. Therefore, the problem is about the viewer, so the question is off-topic here, I'm afraid. You should contact the developer for a solution instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a problem with the viewer.

```
\documentclass[border=15pt,pstricks,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks,pst-node,amsmath}
\begin{document}
    \begin{pspicture}[showgrid,linejoin=1]
    \pnodes(2,3){A}(6,6){C}(6,3){B}(10,6){D}    
    \pcline(A)(C) \bput{:0}(.4){\text{$\dfrac{\sqrt{20}}{4}$}}
                  \naput[nrot=:U]{$\dfrac{\sqrt{12}}{4}+\sqrt[3]{ab}$}
                  \lput*{80}(.8){$\dfrac{\sqrt{20}}{4}$}

    \end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

The output with macOS viewer:

[image]

Comment: Do you use Windows system?

Comment: @chishimutoji The answer says Mac OS

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner Yes, I see but I am using Windows. Sob! I do not know anyone get also the same output as me.

Comment: Compare it with an output of a printer and it should be ok. It depends to your viewer and the resolution of your monitor.

Comment: What does " Compare it with an output of a printer " mean ? I do not understand it clearly.

Comment: @chishimutoji print the pdf file on paper. If the output is ok, then the problem is the viewer in combination with the screen resolution. Herbert is an expert on this topic, I have read more than one book of him. I would trust his advice.